# When I make a draggable clone and drop it in a droppable I cannot drag it again

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, clone, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

When I make a draggable clone and drop it in a droppable I cannot drag it again. How do I do that? Secondly I can only figure out how to us `.append` to add the clone to the droppable. But then it snaps to the top-left corner after any existing element and not the drop position.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#container").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
        }
    });
    $(".product").draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });
});
</script>

<div id="container">
</div>
<div id="products">
    <img id="productid_1" src="images/pic1.jpg" class="product" alt="" title="" />
    <img id="productid_2" src="images/pic2.jpg" class="product" alt="" title="" />
    <img id="productid_3" src="images/pic3.jpg" class="product" alt="" title="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#container").droppable({
        accept: '.product',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).append($("ui.draggable").clone());
            $("#container .product").addClass("item");
            $(".item").removeClass("ui-draggable product");
            $(".item").draggable({
                containment: 'parent',
                grid: [150,150]
            });
        }
    });
    $(".product").draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });
});
```

But I'm not sure if it is nice and clean coding.

Comment: Little late to the party, but that `$(this).append($("ui.draggable").clone());`, should that be `$(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());` ? (without the quotes) since you are loading the object from the callback parameter?

Answer (score 26):

I found this question via Google. I couldn't keep the positions from snapping to the container either, until I changed 'ui.draggable' to 'ui.helper' when appending:

```
$(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
```

Answer (score 5):

For those trying to reposition the dropped item.  Take a look here.

[Jquery drag /drop and clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100896/jquery-drag-drop-and-clone).

I actually had to use code that looks like

```
$(item).css('position', 'absolute');
$(item).css('top', ui.position.top - $(this).position().top);
$(item).css('left', ui.position.left - $(this).position().left);
```

to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, it allows for dragging and dropping a clone, and then replacing it after as needed by another drag and drop.  It also has a callback function parameter which passes back the dropped div object so that you can do something with the jquery selected div once dropped.

```
refreshDragDrop = function(dragClassName,dropDivId, callback) {
  $( "." + dragClassName ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#" + dropDivId,
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#" + dropDivId).droppable({
    accept: '.' + dragClassName,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this),
        maxItemsCount = 1;
      if ($this.children('div').length == maxItemsCount ){
        //too many item,just replace
        $(this).html($(ui.draggable).clone());
        //ui.sender.draggable('cancel');
      } else {
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
      }
      if (typeof callback == "function") callback($this.children('div'));
    }
  });
}
```