# How can I drop a cloned image using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I can't drop a cloned image. But this works when I comment the `helper:"clone"` option.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#drag").draggable({
        helper:"clone",
        revert:"invalid"
    });
    $("#table4").droppable();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the helper is only for visuals.

if you want to clone the image and drop it .. try something like that:

```
$("#table4").droppable({
    accept: "#page",
    tolerance: "touch",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.clone().appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this resolves your issue: [When I make a draggable clone and drop it in a droppable I cannot drag it again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867469/jquery-draggable-clone).

Ps.: A simple search was enough to find this.