# Can't drag a div but can drag an image

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a couple of elements in a widget area that I'd like to drag down to another div.  One of the elements is an image of a blue box and the other is a div with an orange background:[image]

Both have class="widget".  The drag and drop lines are:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.widget').draggable({opacity:'0.5', helper:'clone'});      
        $('#page').droppable({accept:'.widget'});
});
```

The problem is that only the blue image is draggable.

There's a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/2Xu2P/   You can see that  you can drag the blue image but not the orange div.

Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it the right fiddle you got there?

Comment: Sorry: http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/2Xu2P/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xu2P/5/) and it works, if you remove `helper: 'clone'`.

Instead if you really need a cloning functionality, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867469/when-i-make-a-draggable-clone-and-drop-it-in-a-droppable-i-cannot-drag-it-again).

Comment: Actually, yours works if I take the /* */ out from around the helper:'clone': http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/KpF29/  So now let's figure out how this one is different that what I posted.

Comment: Moreover, if you want a clone with the same style of the original div, you should use css classes instead of id, since the clone doesn't have it. That's the main issue you were facing: the div was cloned but didn't have the right style.

Comment: Yes.  It appears that if you drag a div and specify "clone" the clone gets whatever class you've assigned to the div. If you didn't assign a class to the div, the thing you drag is invisible, even though you may have defined the original div completely through its id. The jQuery code won't grab those id styes and apply them to the clone. Good to know!  Thanks for thinking it through with me.