# Drag and drop with the help of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, drag

I'd like to be able to move an object into another with the function draggable of jQuery.
I can move an object in the container and able to move in it.
But when I try to add helper to objects to move, this no longer works.
I want that when I select an item to deposit it in my container, it duplicates itself.
Below is what I have managed to do for the moment:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tjbhjtq/16/)

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    opacity: 0.7,
    snap: '#drop',
    cursor: "move",
    revert: "invalid",
    //helper: "clone"
});

$("#drop").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {

    }
});

<div class="drag">
    <p>Exemple bloc</p>
</div>
<div class="drag">
    <p>Exemple bloc</p>
</div>


<div id="drop">
   <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

The element I deposited in `.drop` clone and must be able to move in the container `.drop`

Comment: Fiddle is nice, but please post the relevant code also.

Comment: The code has been added, thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I make a draggable clone and drop it in a droppable I cannot drag it again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867469/when-i-make-a-draggable-clone-and-drop-it-in-a-droppable-i-cannot-drag-it-again). Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3tjbhjtq/18/)** for you based on the solution given out there..

Comment: this a  [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aitnasser/29m4wzur/) that can help you

Comment: Thank Guruprasad Rao, but once in the container we can not move the item

Comment: @aitnasser Why not post it as an answer? I'd up it if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3tjbhjtq/54/
Here is the code:

```
$(".drag").draggable({

  opacity  : 0.7,
  snap     : '#drop',
  cursor   : "move",
  revert   : "invalid",
  helper   : "clone"

});

$("#drop").droppable({

  drop: function(event, ui) {

    var currenOffset = ui.offset;

    var dropedObjectCss = {
      "position" : "absolute",
      "left"     : currenOffset.left,
      "top"      : currenOffset.top
    };

    var tag = ui.draggable;

    if (tag.data('alreadydropped')) {
      var newItem = tag.css(dropedObjectCss).appendTo( this ); 

      newItem.draggable({
        opacity : 0.7,
        snap    : '#drop',
        cursor  : "move",
        revert  : "invalid"
      });

    } else {
      var newItem = tag.clone().css(dropedObjectCss).appendTo( this );

      newItem.data('alreadydropped', true).draggable({
        opacity : 0.7,
        snap    : '#drop',
        cursor  : "move",
        revert  : "invalid"
      });

    }
  }
});
```

Is this result that you want?

The idea is that we should have different behavior when the item is dropped for the first time 
and when is moved in the container. This is the reason that we keep alreadydropped in data. 
So the first time (else block) we clone the object and append to the container and 
set alreadydropped to true. After this every time when user move the item 
we will enter into if condition and the item will not be cloned and only moved into contaner.

Comment: It is almost that, the element that has been deposited can no longer be displaced in the container, then that's my problem.

Comment: I have change the fiddle and code. Check it again. Now it stay in the same place where is droped. I don't understand. You want to move the element back to the older place?

Comment: Take the example I gave, it's exactly the same thing except that element I deposited in `.drop` clone and must be able to move in the container `.drop`

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Can you me explained ? thank you

Comment: Check the answer again.

Comment: Hi @Manudog, mark the GeorgiNamurov's answer as correct answer if it answers your question. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

this a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aitnasser/29m4wzur/) that can help you

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="origin" class="fbox">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" id="one" title="one" class="draggable" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" id="two" title="two" class="draggable" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/160x100" id="three" title="three" />
    </div>
    <p>CONTAINAIR</p>
    <div id="drop" class="fbox">

    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    $(".draggable").draggable({ cursor: "crosshair", revert: "invalid"});

$("#drop").droppable({ accept: ".draggable",

  drop: function(event, ui) {

    console.log("drop");

    $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");

    var dropped = ui.draggable;
    var droppedOn = $(this);

    $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
  },

  over: function(event, elem) {

    $(this).addClass("over");

    console.log("over");

  },

  out: function(event, elem) {

    $(this).removeClass("over");

  }

});

$("#drop").sortable();

$("#origin").droppable({ accept: ".draggable", drop: function(event, ui) {

  console.log("drop");

  $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");

  var dropped = ui.draggable;
  var droppedOn = $(this);

  $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);

}});
```

**CSS**

```
#origin
{
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#origin img, #drop img {
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#drop
{
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 120px;
}
.over {
  border: solid 5px purple;
}
.draggable
{
  border: solid 2px gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `draggable` function to the item after it is cloned and add a class to it. After if the item is returned to the initial position you delete it:

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="drag">
    <p>Exemple bloc 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="drag">
    <p>Exemple bloc 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="drop">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
#container{
  width: 100%;
}
.drag {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #505050;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

#drop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

**jQuery code**

```
makeDragable($(".drag"));

$("#drop").droppable({
  accept: ".drag",
  drop: function(event, ui) {

    if( $(ui.draggable).hasClass("cloned") ) {        
       $(ui.draggable).css(ui.offset).css("position", "absolute");      
       return;    
    }

    var item = $(ui.draggable).clone();
    item.addClass("cloned");
    $(this).append(item);
    makeDragable(item);
  }
});

$("#container").droppable({
  accept: ".cloned",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).detach();
  }
});

function makeDragable(item) {
  item.draggable({
    opacity: 0.7,
    cursor: "move",
    helper: "clone"
  });
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/d01L0ryx/)