# How to retain drawn boxes and path on page refresh mxgraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, mxgraph, draw.io

i want to **retain** drawn `boxes` and path once page is refreshed.

i'm using **mxgraph** https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/manual.html

**Question:**  once the **drawing** is done, if i do page **refresh** it should **retain** the same **drawing** by storing drawing data into localStorage.

**NOTE:** i want to get `json object` of drawn `canvas`, and re-construct it back from that `object` on page refresh.

**Below video shows how to draw:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1McTMz3e8I_quOcLGt2CtaQhqif3R31qs/view

```css
https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/
```

```html
<!--
  Copyright (c) 2006-2013, JGraph Ltd
  
  Dynamic toolbar example for mxGraph. This example demonstrates changing the
  state of the toolbar at runtime.
-->
<html>
<head>
 <title>Toolbar example for mxGraph</title>

 <!-- Sets the basepath for the library if not in same directory -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    mxBasePath = 'https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src';
  </script>

  <!-- Loads and initializes the library -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src/js/mxClient.js"></script>

 <!-- Example code -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
  // Program starts here. Creates a sample graph in the
  // DOM node with the specified ID. This function is invoked
  // from the onLoad event handler of the document (see below).
  function main()
  {
   // Checks if browser is supported
   if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported())
   {
    // Displays an error message if the browser is
    // not supported.
    mxUtils.error('Browser is not supported!', 200, false);
   }
   else
   {
    // Defines an icon for creating new connections in the connection handler.
    // This will automatically disable the highlighting of the source vertex.
    mxConnectionHandler.prototype.connectImage = new mxImage('images/connector.gif', 16, 16);

    // Creates the div for the toolbar
    var tbContainer = document.createElement('div');
    tbContainer.style.position = 'absolute';
    tbContainer.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    tbContainer.style.padding = '2px';
    tbContainer.style.left = '0px';
    tbContainer.style.top = '0px';
    tbContainer.style.width = '24px';
    tbContainer.style.bottom = '0px';
    
    document.body.appendChild(tbContainer);
   
    // Creates new toolbar without event processing
    var toolbar = new mxToolbar(tbContainer);
    toolbar.enabled = false
    
    // Creates the div for the graph
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.style.position = 'absolute';
    container.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    container.style.left = '24px';
    container.style.top = '0px';
    container.style.right = '0px';
    container.style.bottom = '0px';
    container.style.background = 'url("editors/images/grid.gif")';

    document.body.appendChild(container);
    
    // Workaround for Internet Explorer ignoring certain styles
    if (mxClient.IS_QUIRKS)
    {
     document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
     new mxDivResizer(tbContainer);
     new mxDivResizer(container);
    }
 
    // Creates the model and the graph inside the container
    // using the fastest rendering available on the browser
    var model = new mxGraphModel();
    var graph = new mxGraph(container, model);

    // Enables new connections in the graph
    graph.setConnectable(true);
    graph.setMultigraph(false);

    // Stops editing on enter or escape keypress
    var keyHandler = new mxKeyHandler(graph);
    var rubberband = new mxRubberband(graph);
    
    var addVertex = function(icon, w, h, style)
    {
     var vertex = new mxCell(null, new mxGeometry(0, 0, w, h), style);
     vertex.setVertex(true);
    
     var img = addToolbarItem(graph, toolbar, vertex, icon);
     img.enabled = true;
     
     graph.getSelectionModel().addListener(mxEvent.CHANGE, function()
     {
      var tmp = graph.isSelectionEmpty();
      mxUtils.setOpacity(img, (tmp) ? 100 : 20);
      img.enabled = tmp;
     });
    };
    
    addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/rectangle.gif', 100, 40, '');
    addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/rounded.gif', 100, 40, 'shape=rounded');
    addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/ellipse.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=ellipse');
    addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/rhombus.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=rhombus');
    addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/triangle.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=triangle');
    addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/cylinder.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=cylinder');
    addVertex('https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/images/actor.gif', 30, 40, 'shape=actor');
   }
  }

  function addToolbarItem(graph, toolbar, prototype, image)
  {
   // Function that is executed when the image is dropped on
   // the graph. The cell argument points to the cell under
   // the mousepointer if there is one.
   var funct = function(graph, evt, cell, x, y)
   {
    graph.stopEditing(false);

    var vertex = graph.getModel().cloneCell(prototype);
    vertex.geometry.x = x;
    vertex.geometry.y = y;
     
    graph.addCell(vertex);
    graph.setSelectionCell(vertex);
   }
   
   // Creates the image which is used as the drag icon (preview)
   var img = toolbar.addMode(null, image, function(evt, cell)
   {
    var pt = this.graph.getPointForEvent(evt);
    funct(graph, evt, cell, pt.x, pt.y);
   });
   
   // Disables dragging if element is disabled. This is a workaround
   // for wrong event order in IE. Following is a dummy listener that
   // is invoked as the last listener in IE.
   mxEvent.addListener(img, 'mousedown', function(evt)
   {
    // do nothing
   });
   
   // This listener is always called first before any other listener
   // in all browsers.
   mxEvent.addListener(img, 'mousedown', function(evt)
   {
    if (img.enabled == false)
    {
     mxEvent.consume(evt);
    }
   });
      
   mxUtils.makeDraggable(img, graph, funct);
   
   return img;
  }

 </script>
</head>

<!-- Calls the main function after the page has loaded. Container is dynamically created. -->
<body onload="main();" >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have changed my question please have a look, then down vote, please please

Answer (score 4):

This uses the XML encoding of mxgraph. You see this code in [one of the examples](http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/diagrameditor.html) of mxGraph. While it is not json, it is very easy to turn into json, and can be edited or saved as you wish. Now it it stored in localStorage as you asked.

Add the following lines at the end of your main function (after the last call to addVertex):

```
// read state on load 
if(window.localStorage.graphState){
    var doc = mxUtils.parseXml(window.localStorage.graphState);
    var dec = new mxCodec(doc);
    dec.decode(doc.documentElement, graph.getModel());
}

// save state on change
graph.getModel().addListener('change',function(){
    var codec = new mxCodec();
    window.localStorage.graphState = codec.encode(
            graph.getModel()
        ).outerHTML;
});
```

### Update using JSON

**Update 2: Switched to my own custom html2json and json2html implementation to make the answer fully self-contained**

If you do need a proper JSON object, you can convert from xml to json and back. Below you can see I stringify and parse the json object, this is only needed to save it in localStorage though.

First add these two functions to convert from html/xml to json and from json back to html/xml:

```
function html2json(html){
    if(html.nodeType==3){
        return {
            "tagName":"#text",
            "content":html.textContent
        }
    }
    var element = {
        "tagName":html.tagName
    };

    if(html.getAttributeNames().length>0){
        element.attributes = html.getAttributeNames().reduce(
            function(acc,at){acc[at]=html.getAttribute(at); return acc;},
            {}
        );
    }

    if(html.childNodes.length>0){
        element.children = Array.from(html.childNodes)
            .filter(
                function(el){
                    return el.nodeType!=3
                    ||el.textContent.trim().length>0
                })
            .map(function(el){return html2json(el);});
    }
    return element;
}

function json2html(json){
    var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, json.tagName);

    var addAttributes = function(jsonNode, node){
        if(jsonNode.attributes){
            Object.keys(jsonNode.attributes).map(
                function(name){
                    node.setAttribute(name,jsonNode.attributes[name]);
                }
            );
        }
    }

    var addChildren = function(jsonNode,node){
        if(jsonNode.children){
            jsonNode.children.map(
                function(jsonChildNode){
                    json2htmlNode(jsonChildNode,node);
                }
            );
        }
    }

    var json2htmlNode = function(jsonNode,parent){
        if(jsonNode.tagName=="#text"){
            return xmlDoc.createTextNode(jsonNode.content);
        }

        var node = xmlDoc.createElement(jsonNode.tagName);

        addAttributes(jsonNode,node);
        addChildren(jsonNode,node);

        parent.appendChild(node);
    }

    addAttributes(json,xmlDoc.firstElementChild);
    addChildren(json,xmlDoc.firstElementChild);

    return xmlDoc;
}
```

Then change my JavaScript snippet from above like this to transform the xml into json and back:

```
// read state on load 
if(window.localStorage.graphState){ 
    var doc = json2html(JSON.parse(localStorage.graphState));   
  var dec = new mxCodec(doc);
  dec.decode(doc.documentElement, graph.getModel());
}

// save state on change
graph.getModel().addListener('change',function(){
        var codec = new mxCodec();      
    window.localStorage.graphState = JSON.stringify(html2json(codec.encode(
      graph.getModel()
    )));
});
```

Comment: tried but it is not working , https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/VNRLVP,   Click on **FORK** then save as anonymous, then you can **Edit**

Comment: Even in your pen it is working for me. Maybe your codepen settings are resetting localstorage or your browser settings are clearing local storage? I can see the graphstate being stored, and on refresh it gets loaded again. I tested in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, all three work fine, and load the drawing after refreshing and even after closing and reopening the browser.

Comment: I just tried the codepen and as Tom says it worked for me. I drew two objects, linked them together and then did a F5 to refresh the page.  The objects came back exactly as I drew them

Comment: @K Scandrett, @Tom, sorry for my mistake it is working fine,  but I need `json object` to send it to backend.  Sending `xml` to `mongodb` is not a good idea.   I need to get `json`  please help me with this one.  Thanks in advance

Comment: I have switched to my own custom html2json and json2html implementation to make the answer fully self-contained. You can see the code work here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yrWmQO **just make sure you DELETE your localStorage first, or it will give an error!**

Comment: @Tom, where can i find source code for this one http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/editors/diagrameditor.html (your one of the examples)

Comment: Here: https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/tree/master/javascript/examples