# jQuery drag and drop is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

HTML code.

```
<div class="pin-list">
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>

<div id="drop-area">

</div>
```

JS code.

```
$( ".pin-list div" ).draggable({
    helper: "clone"
});

$( "#drop-area" ).droppable({
    accept: ".pin-list div",
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active"
});
```

I created this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evohpk7k/4/) to explain what is going

It should work without any issues but I think I'm missing something.

Comment: If you're using ```helper: "clone"``` option than you have to clone the ```clone``` node and append it to the ```droppable``` container manually in the ```drop``` event handler as shown e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867469/when-i-make-a-draggable-clone-and-drop-it-in-a-droppable-i-cannot-drag-it-again

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by making the following changes.

JS:

```
$( "#dragme div" ).draggable({
});

$( "#drop-area" ).droppable({
accept: "#dragme div",
activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
hoverClass: "ui-state-active"
});
```

Also I made a small change to the HTML:

```
<div id=dragme class="pin-list ui-widget-content">
   <div>test</div>
   <div>test</div>
   <div>test</div>
   <div>test</div>
 </div>

<div id="drop-area">

</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0o5vksas/)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
<div class="pin-list">
  <div>test1</div>
  <div>test2</div>
  <div>test3</div>
  <div>test4</div>
</div>

<div id="drop-area">

</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".pin-list div" ).draggable();
    $( "#drop-area" ).droppable();
})
</script>
<body>
</html>
```