# How to clone an element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, clone, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to implement a drag& drop feature using jQuery & it works great, now I want to replace the dragged element by another in the old place.

I'm using the `clone()` method but since I'm new to jQuery, the code I wrote clones the element infinitely, can somebody help me?

This is my code:

```
<script> 
$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable(
        {
            drag : function(event, ui) {
                $(this).clone().appendTo(this)
            }
        });

    $(".droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight")
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You clone the element within the drag handler. The function assigned to drag: is called constantly while you drag the element. Assign the handler to either start: or stop: to clone it when you start or stop dragging but not repeatedly while dragging.

Comment: yes i fugured that out , but how can i assign to these methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I make a draggable clone and drop it in a droppable I cannot drag it again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867469/when-i-make-a-draggable-clone-and-drop-it-in-a-droppable-i-cannot-drag-it-again)

Answer (score 0):

This basically works. But you'll have to tweak it according your needs.

```js
var dropclone;
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        dropclone = ui.helper.clone();
    }
});
$( ".droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function() {
        $('body').append(dropclone);
    }
});
```