# How to turn a png into a button that when clicked makes a draggable png

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a house designing game of sorts and i'm wondering how i could make it so that there is a png of a flower pot in a set position.

When clicked a draggable png of the flower pot appears and the player can do it indefinitely.

this is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="buttons">
  <span class="button" id="up">up</span>
  <span class="button" id="down">down</span>
  <div><span>Z-index: </span><span id="index"></span></div>
</div>
<div id="images">
  <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/wum2y8.jpg" id="background">
  <img class="draggable" src="http://i64.tinypic.com/jac9sj.jpg">
  <img class="draggable" src="http://i64.tinypic.com/se6gia.jpg">
  <img class="draggable" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/205p9v6.jpg">
  <!--more img.draggable elements -->
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
});
var selectedLayer;
$(".draggable").click(function() { 
    selectedLayer = this; 
  $("#index").html(parseInt($(selectedLayer).css("z-index")))
}) 
$("#up").click(function() { 
    x = parseInt($(selectedLayer).css("z-index")) + 1;
  $(selectedLayer).css('z-index', x); 
  $("#index").html(x)
}) //ends function
$("#down").click(function() { 
    x = parseInt($(selectedLayer).css("z-index")) - 1; 
  $(selectedLayer).css('z-index', x); 
  $("#index").html(x) 
})
```

full example:
https://jsfiddle.net/okcjt5vf/312/

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: let me see if i understood correctly, you want the user to be able to click on an object (from a menu or something similar) and be able to place it on the screen without the object disappearing from the menu? or i completely misunderstood your question?

Comment: Exactly what i mean - Juan Antonio Orozco

Answer (score 0):

You may use a helper on the `draggable` function to clone the object, but you will also need to do some modifications:

**HTML**

- move the dragables to a new div with id  `menu` outside of `#images`
- add the class miniature to the draggables (so they can be shown all at once)

---

```
<div id="buttons">
  <span class="button" id="up">up</span>
  <span class="button" id="down">down</span>
  <div><span>Z-index: </span><span id="index"></span></div>
</div>
<div id="menu">
  <img class="draggable miniature" src="http://i64.tinypic.com/jac9sj.jpg">
  <img class="draggable miniature" src="http://i64.tinypic.com/se6gia.jpg">
  <img class="draggable miniature" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/205p9v6.jpg">
  <!--more img.draggable.miniature elements -->
</div>
<div id="images">
  <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/wum2y8.jpg" id="background">
</div>
```

**CSS**

- add the class `miniature`
- remove `position:relative` from `#images`

  - this is no needed because draggable will take care of the positioning, if left may cause a snapping-like bug when releasing the item after its added
- delete the `.draggable` class

  - again, this is no needed because draggable will take care of the positioning

---

```
#images {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 778px;
}

.miniature {
  height: 20px;
}
```

**js**

- add a helper to the `draggable` widget, this whelper will clone the object and remove the `miniature` class to make it full size again

---

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
  helper: function(event) {
      return $(this).clone().removeClass("miniature")
  }
});
```

- add the droppable widget to the `#images` div, this will make the div accept the `draggable` items
- add the drop listener to the `droppable` widget, on this listener you should clone the item and add it to the container. also you should add a `mousedown` listener to the new element to set the selected layer

---

```
$("#images").droppable({
  accept: ".draggable",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var new_item = $(ui.helper).clone();

    new_item.removeClass('draggable');
    new_item.mousedown(setLayer);
    new_item.draggable();

    $(this).append(new_item);
  }
});

setLayer = function() {
  selectedLayer = this;
  $("#index").html(parseInt($(selectedLayer).css("z-index")))
}
```

With this changes this would be the result:

[image: result of the suggested code editions]

full code on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/npc1sfmu/5/

Comment: also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867469/when-i-make-a-draggable-clone-and-drop-it-in-a-droppable-i-cannot-drag-it-again